# how to run openssl command from a java application

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, openssl

I use the following code to run Windows commands from Java application. I tried some windows commands such as: `ver` and it works file with me. The command I need to use in the application is `openssl`. I work on Windows, so I downloaded `openssl` for Windows. I tried the following command in the command line window, and it works fine. But, when I try it from the Java application, all what I get is Done. I don't get the output. Can anybody help ?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*; 

public class DebianChecker 
{ 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
try 
{ 
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c openssl s_client -connect
gmail.com:443"); 
p.waitFor(); 
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
String line=reader.readLine(); 
while(line!=null) 
{ 
System.out.println(line); 
line=reader.readLine(); 
} 

} 
catch(IOException e1) {} 
catch(InterruptedException e2) {} 

System.out.println("Done"); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line
p.waitFor();

waitFor() waits for the process to end. So, by the time you get the InputStream, the process has already completed.